# Bad variable name in WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am getting error below error while executing a program.

> sh: 1: export:
>   Files/WindowsApps/CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_1804.2019.522.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc:/mnt/c/Program:
>   bad variable name

I know it is the space in "Program File" that is messing up.
Also,  I did not create the program. There are lot of scripts so i am not sure which script is calling it. My window version is Windows 10 Insider Preview 10.0.19041.21 (vb_release).

How can i fix it ? Can i edit path variable or something like that.

Comment: You can easily create a link called Program that points to Program Files. For myself, I would dig through and find the faulty script and fix it.

Comment: How you are executing the program? tell us the command. If it is a bash script run it with bash -x so you can see why it is failing. Looks like there is an error parsing $PATH

Comment: Well, i am using a script from Kaldi to execute it.

Comment: Is it possible to change the path access via profile ?

Comment: What is the output of `echo $SHELL`?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use the 8.3 names.

In windows command prompt, type

```
cd /d C:\
dir /x
```

You will see something like

```
08/03/2020  20:20    <DIR>                       $WINDOWS.~BT
03/11/2018  16:56    <DIR>                       dell
08/03/2020  22:33    <DIR>                       ESD
06/12/2019  03:16    <DIR>                       inetpub
19/03/2019  04:52    <DIR>                       PerfLogs
06/12/2019  04:17    <DIR>          PROGRA~1     Program Files
06/12/2019  04:17    <DIR>          PROGRA~2     Program Files (x86)
03/03/2020  15:24    <DIR>          PROGRA~3     ProgramData
05/12/2019  20:39    <DIR>                       Users
12/02/2020  18:46    <DIR>                       Windows
```

In this case, if you want **Program Files** use **progra~1** (it ignores case).  If you want to use **Program Files (x86)** use **progra~2**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if my issue which I solved is same as yours, however, it looks very similar. I hope my steps can be of any help.

My issue was happening when I was trying to launch my wsl/ubuntu from Win10. I would get the following error:

> -sh: 6: export: Files/WindowsApps/CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_2020.1804.7.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc:/mnt/c/Program:
>   bad variable name

1. Make sure you are in root. `sudo su -`
2. `chsh -s $(which bash)`
3. Close current WSL window and launch new one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I made a switch to ubuntu. If i use window, I will let you know if this work.