# bad variable name error on WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

A similar question has been asked with no satisfying answer. I installed kaldi on WSL and when running a script I get this error, that apparantely has to do with "Program Files".

```
sh: 1: export: Files/WindowsApps/CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_2004.2021.222.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc:/mnt/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program: bad variable name
```

One of the answers was to make a link "Program" to "Program Files". But, it fails:
/mnt/c$ sudo ln -s /mnt/c/"Program Files" Program
ln: failed to create symbolic link 'Program'
Making the link on the windows side succeeds but has no effect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why I obtain this error when I try to perform this simple bash script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506415/why-i-obtain-this-error-when-i-try-to-perform-this-simple-bash-script)

Comment: @user535733 This does not look like a duplicate of that question *at all*

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds you sure?  Aside from the actual path used, this error is pretty much duplicated there.

Comment: @muru I've seriously thought about changing my profile to read "I've been using Linux 4 times longer than muru, but muru knows 4 times more than I do about it."  (i.e. Muru, you rock!). But I'm fairly sure in this case that the linked question is similar in error only. That one was caused by an obviously bad use of the `export` command. I could be wrong, but I'm pretty dang certain this is a variable quoting issue that is causing the `export` to fail. I'm sure we can find another question that might be a better "duplicate" candidate, but the WSL aspects also make this one a bit more "special".

Comment: Seems to really be an almost exact duplicate of [this one](https://askubuntu.com/q/1215961/1165986), but there's really no good answer on that one either.  Since that OP abandoned WSL for "pure" Ubuntu, I don't see them ever accepting an answer (they pretty much said so in a comment).  For that reason, I'd propose that we close the earlier question in favor of this one (or find another duplicate).  It's not usual, but I've seen instances across Stack sites where it was done for reasons like this.

Comment: Please [edit] and provide the link to the 'similar question' to you refer to in your question

Answer (score 1):

I have a hunch that this is caused by something in your script or startup files (assuming `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`) not properly quoting the `PATH` variable.  Because WSL appends the Windows path to the WSL path automatically, it's adding some path elements with "Program Files" in, which is correct.

But it does require proper variable quoting.  Check your script for use of `$PATH` and quote it (or add the potentially offending lines to your question if you need help with that).  If you don't see anything suspect in the script, then also check your `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile`.

*Edit/update*:  I'm fairly sure the offending line will be in the script which is being processed through `dash` (i.e. `sh`).  Bash can handle this just fine without additional quoting:

```
> export PATH=$PATH:newpath
> echo $?
0
> echo $PATH
> # outputs correct PATH, even with spaces in the Windows path
```

However, run `sh` and try the same:

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:newpath
sh: 1: export: Files/NVIDIA: bad variable name
$ export PATH="$PATH":newpath
$ echo $?
0
$ echo $PATH
# outputs correct PATH, even with spaces in the Windows path
```

There's also a "bandaid" solution to disable the WSL feature that appends the Windows path to the WSL/Linux path.  You can do this by creating (or editing if it already exists) `/etc/wsl.conf` and adding the following lines:

```
[interop]
appendWindowsPath=false
```

Then stop the instance with `wsl --terminate Ubuntu` (assuming the default distro name), and restart WSL.

It's not a *good* permanent solution, IMHO, since it makes it far more difficult to run Windows apps (such as VSCode) when they aren't in the path.

Better to figure out the core issue and fix it in the scripts.

Comment: @steeldriver I was thinking that, but then I figured the mangled PATH might still occur in `~/.bashrc` and then, since it's exported, would be picked up by the script in question (which is likely running under a `sh` shebang).  That said, the more I think about it, the more I believe the quoting problem probably lies within the script in question.

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, I do mention that Windows *appends* the Windows path in the question, but there's also some *prepending* going on for some reason -- `/mnt/c/Program Files/WindowsApps/CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_2004.2021.222.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc` is getting prepended, and that's unusual in WSL.  You are right that it shouldn't be WSL that is doing this part.

Comment: @steeldriver I see the confusion - My statement was a bit ambiguous.  When I said "prepending the Windows path to the actual Ubuntu UWP app", I meant that app path (not the "Windows path").  Edited to try to remove some of the ambiguity.

Comment: @steeldriver Oops - I was thinking that the first path was prepended, but now I see that the entire error is part of the *appended* path (including the UWP path).  I'll edit my answer to remove that part.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah it's getting tokenized as `export PATH=everything-up-to-first-whitespace everything-up-to-next-whitespace` which is equivalent to `export PATH=everything-up-to-first-whitespace` followed by `export everything-up-to-next-whitespace`. Another solution is simply to make sure `$PATH` is quoted on the RHS of the assignment.

Comment: @steeldriver *"Another solution is simply to make sure $PATH is quoted on the RHS of the assignment."* That's exactly the solution, I believe.  Just have to find the offending line and fix it, which will be up to the OP to do.

Comment: BTW your observation about `sh` versus `bash` is spot on - see [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68748/65304), in particular the section about the RHS of an assignment in **Where you can omit the double quotes** *Note that you do need the double quotes after `export`, because it's an ordinary builtin, not a keyword. This is only true in some shells such as dash, zsh (in sh emulation), yash or posh; bash and ksh both treat export specially.*

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in
https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=1472885
You need to remove the windows paths from $PATH, and you do that by creating /etc/wsl.conf with the following text:
[interop]
appendWindowsPath=False
Then close the WSL window, wait 8 sec, and relauch.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that being part of the problem in the first paragraph of my answer yesterday, and gave the `wsl.conf` option as a workaround, so you should accept that answer.  Also note that removing the Windows path from WSL will reduce its functionality and usefulness, so it's recommended that you correct the quoting error in the script instead.

Answer (score 0):

I may be a little late to the game here, but posting this in case anyone else stumbles across this thread. I was having this same issue with a fresh install of WSL using Ubuntu, and it was fixed by simply running these commands (as root) in WSL:

```
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
```

All I had to do was restart my WSL terminal after this and the issue disappeared. Hope this helps someone!