# WSL: No such file or directory when installing a setup.py for a third-party

Tags: software-installation, python, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to run a setup.py file for a third-party package in my Ubuntu WSL:

```
$ sudo env PATH=$PATH python setup.py develop
```

The [setup.py file](https://github.com/zju3dv/EasyMocap/blob/master/setup.py) is designed to modularize the package, and I'm running it with sudo because I do not have admin write privliges. However, I get the error:

```
env: ‘Files/WindowsApps/CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_2004.2022.1.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc:/mnt/c/Program’: No such file or directory
```

I can't figure out why it is trying to look in `/mnt/c/Program`. My Windows data on this shared PC lives at `/mnt/c/Users/username`, but there is nothing in the setup.py code relating to directory paths. There are no open or closed issues on the repo's site that discuss the same error, so I am assuming that this issue is an WSL/Ubuntu nuance.

---

The third-party package installation instructions are:

```
git clone https://github.com/zju3dv/EasyMocap.git
conda create -n easymocap python=3.9 -y
conda activate easymocap
wget -c https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu111/torch-1.9.1%2Bcu111-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl
wget -c https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu111/torchvision-0.10.1%2Bcu111-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl
python3 -m pip install ./torch-1.9.1+cu111-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl
python3 -m pip install ./torchvision-0.10.1+cu111-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
# install pyrender if you have a screen
python3 -m pip install pyrender
python setup.py develop
```

Comment: This is almost certainly because of the default WSL "appendWindowsPath" setting and Windows having path components containing whitespace - see for example [bad variable name error on WSL](https://askubuntu.com/a/1355022/178692). See if it works with `env PATH="$PATH"` in place of `env PATH=$PATH`

Comment: Yeesh, another trivial typo issue. Thank you!